# What exactly does ${\rm PGL}(n,K)$ represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, quotient-spaces

Suppose $V:=GL(n,K)$ denotes the general linear group and $V_I$ denotes center of $V$. Then what exactly does $V/V_I$ represent? I would be appreciate if you give a similar good example for better understanding. (The origin of this question is General projective
transformations ${\rm PGL}(n,K)$ and special  projective
transformations ${\rm PSL}(n,K)$)

Comment: The identity element of a vector space is the zero vector. It spans a trivial subspace. In other words $V_I = \{0\}$ and $V / V_I$ is generated by the equivalence relation on $V$ where $u\sim v \iff u-v\in V_I$ i.e $u=v$. So for all intents and purposes $V = V / V_I$.

Comment: So why $PGL(n,K)=GL/ z$ where $z$ is the center of $GL(n,K)$. isn't center of $GL(n,K)$ equal to $V_I$?

Comment: The center of a group is the subset of those elements that commute with all elements in the group. What makes you think a center must always be trivial?

Comment: $PGL(n,K) = GL/z$ is merely the definition of what a projective linear group is (according to wiki). I don't understand what your question(s) are.

Comment: According to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960342/center-of-general-linear-group $V_I=a I$

Comment: $I$ is the identity transformation of $V$ i.e $I:V\to V, x\mapsto x$. The space in question, therefore, is $V_I = \{aI : a\in K\}$. This is a subspace of $\mbox{End}(V)$. The meaning of $V/V_I$ is no longer clear to me.

Comment: By this question I want to know the structure of ${\rm PGL}(n,K)$ and ${\rm PSL}(n,K)$. maybe my question is wrong?